# Richfaces: menu key binding

Tags: menu, richfaces, key-bindings, hotkeys

I got a richface issue that rather looks very easy, but i can't find the answer.
I want to acces a (dropdown)menu with keybindings. Once the menu has focus i can use the arrow buttons without a problem. I just cant get the 'focus' on my menu with a hotkey

XHTML:

```
<rich:dropDownMenu  
      binding="#{menuBarBean.menuBar}" 
      id="main-menu" 
      showEvent="mouseup" 
      onclick="showMenu();" 
      />


<rich:hotKey enabledInInput="true" key="ctrl+M" onkeyup="displayMenu()" preventDefault="true" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function displayMenu(){
  #{rich:component('main-menu')}.show();
  **// Do something that sets focus on the richface menu component**
}
```

In short:
How to get the focus on

```
#{rich:component('main-menu')}
```

with:

```
<rich:hotKey />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a `.focus()` method that focuses things:

```
#{rich:component('main-menu')}.element.focus();
```

Comment: This works in FF and Chrome.. just that bastard IE is doing annoying again. Thanks for the right direction!

Comment: Solved it also for IE. IE (8) seems to need a 'tabindex' else it cant/wont focus the element. When that was added, it went all fine.